# Function Query.where() called with invalid data

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to set two conditions for displaying data. But such error occurs in the browser console.

```
Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined
```

ts:

How to fix it?

```
  this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection<Message>('messages', ref => {
    let query: firebase.default.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.default.firestore.Query = ref;
    query = query.where('receiverId', '==', this.receiverId);
    query = query.where('senderId', '==', this._cs.senderId);
    return query;
  });
  this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine but as the error message text says one of your variables `this.receiverId` or `this._cs.senderId` has the value `undefined` and that causes the error. Just make sure not to have `undefined` there by putting some kind of fallback values.

```js
 this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection<Message>('messages', ref => {
    let query: firebase.default.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.default.firestore.Query = ref;
    query = query.where('receiverId', '==', this.receiverId || '');
    query = query.where('senderId', '==', this._cs.senderId || '');
    return query;
  });
  this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
```